# Twitter error in application

Tags: android, twitter, runtime-error

Twitter error in application

```
 E/Twitter: Invalid json: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>
        com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
```

Answer (score 4):

Please go to [my twitter app settings page](https://apps.twitter.com/).

Step 1 : Select your app.
Step 2 : Select `Settings` from 4 tabs.
Step 3 : Find `Callback URLs` section and give these values: **twittersdk://** and **twitterkit-yourTwitterAPIKeyHere://** ( if you have setup Twitter SDK on iOS, too, otherwise enter any valid URL, i.e. google home page URL :-) ). Each time you enter these values, click on `Add a callback URl` button, it'll verify the URL you've entered.
Step 4 : Click on `Update Settings` button at the bottom of the page.

After completing this process, you'll get a valid request token and can continue Twitter integration.

You can read the changelog [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/action-required-sign-in-with-twitter-users-must-whitelist-callback-urls/105342).

Hope this helped.

Comment: No it didnt work yet

Comment: @AmitPrasad, how many callbacks have you set up in Twitter console?

Comment: one callback do i have to set more

Comment: @AmitPrasad, Yeah, you have to. It requires minimum 2 callback URLs to be set. Please set your web-app URL or google's home page URL. And follow Step 4.

Comment: It works for me for both Android and iOS. I have three URLs: twittersdk:// , twitterkit-yourTwitterAPIKeyHere:// and my domain url.